# Window Screenshot background black

Tags: macos, screen-capture

I use the window screenshot feature a lot (`Shift+Cmd+4 SPC`)

There is supposed to be a window shadow, but instead, the background is black.

[image: Window with black background]

My desktop wallpaper is not black.

Comment: Precisely which Mac, what OS? Does it affect all drop-shadowed screenshots?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. If you open the screenshot with Preview, do you see a checkered pattern or is the background black? Is the picture in your question the actual screenshot you get when pressing Shift+Command+4+Space? Have you enabled accessibility options (in System Preferences > Accessibility > Display)?

Comment: @Tetsujin MacOS 11.4 It does affect all screenshots.

Comment: @jaume When I open it in Preview, it still shows the black background, so it is not a rendering problem. Yes, this is actually what I get when I press Shift+Command+4 Space. In my display accessibility options, I have reduce motion and reduce transparency enabled. I tried turning them off, but it doesn't change the results.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you switch screenshot file type to jpg. Switching back to default (png) solves the problem.

You can do that via terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture type png;killall SystemUIServer
```